# VB.NET How to delete a folder that exists in a portable device

Tags: vb.net, delete-operator

I have copy a folder from my computer to a portable device using Shell32.Shell

```
Dim SrcPath = "my path"
Dim tmpShell As Shell
Dim tmpFolder As Folder
Dim destinationPath As String

destinationPath = "destinationpath here"
' destinationPath  = "::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\\\?\usb#vid_05c6&pid_9039&mi_00#7&105d921&0&0000#{6ac27878-a6fa-4155-ba85-f98f491d4f33}\SID-{10001,,11280285696}\{00000056-0001-0001-0000-000000000000}"

' because it is coming from tmpShell.BrowseForFolder in another function

tmpShell = New Shell

tmpFolder = tmpShell.NameSpace(destinationPath)
tmpFolder.CopyHere(SrcPath)
```

For now it is OK, but I want to delete this folder '***::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\?\usb#vid_05c6&pid_9039&mi_00#7&105d921&0&0000#{6ac27878-a6fa-4155-ba85-f98f491d4f33}\SID-{10001,,11280285696}{00000056-0001-0001-0000-000000000000}***'.

The path was obtained using:

```
Dim tmpShell As New Shell
Dim tmpFolder As Folder
tmpFolder = tmpShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose the device iternal storage folder", 0, 0)
dim the path = tmpFolder.Items.Item.Path
```

I can't use

```
IO.File.Delete()
```

Please help

Comment: Have a look at: https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32.shfileoperation

Comment: No not work , the same exception message {"The path is not of a legal form."}

Comment: How did you generate the path to that folder?

Comment: Dim tmpShell As New Shell

Dim tmpFolder As Folder

tmpFolder = tmpShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose the device iternal storage folder", 0, 0)       

dim the path = tmpFolder.Items.Item.Path

Comment: [Windows Portable Devices: Deleting Resources](https://laptrinhx.com/windows-portable-devices-deleting-resources-2341594271/) looks to have the information you need. I don't have a portable device that I would try it with.